# Setup of development environment of QGIS on windows with qt creator

Tags: qgis, c++, qt

Can anyone help me in setting up environment for working on QGIS on windows using qt-creator?

I am using qt creator version 1.3.1,qt version 4.6 and QGIS version 1.8.